# Linq Query - get current month plus previous months

Tags: linq

I need to build a Linq query that will show the results as follow:

```
Data:

Sales   Month
----------------------
10      January
20      February
30      March
40      April
50      May
60      June
70      July
80      August
90      September
100     October
110     November
120     December
```

I need to get the results based on this scenario:
**month x = month x + previous month**
that will result in:

```
Sales   Month
--------------------
10      January
30      February (30 = February 20 + January 10)
60      March    (60 = March 30 + February 30)
100     April    (100 = April 40 + March 60)
.........
```

Any help how to build this query ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you talking about linq2sql or linq query on objects?

Comment: Hi Shoaib: linq query on objects

Comment: Broadly, `Zip` the sequence with `[`the sequence `.Skip(1)` `]`. Without knowing the types you're actually using, we can't offer more details, let alone code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wanted it in LINQ...

```
void Main()
{
    List<SaleCount> sales = new List<SaleCount>() {
        new SaleCount() { Sales = 10, Month = 1 },
        new SaleCount() { Sales = 20, Month = 2 },
        new SaleCount() { Sales = 30, Month = 3 },
        new SaleCount() { Sales = 40, Month = 4 },
        ...
    };

    var query = sales.Select ((s, i) => new
    {
        CurrentMonth = s.Month,
        CurrentAndPreviousSales = s.Sales + sales.Take(i).Sum(sa => sa.Sales)
    });
}

public class SaleCount
{
    public int Sales { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
}
```

...but in my opinion, this is a case where coming up with some fancy LINQ isn't going to be as clear as just writing out the code that the LINQ query is going to generate. This also doesn't scale. For example, including multiple years worth of data gets even more hairy when it wouldn't have to if it was just written out the "old fashioned way".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want add up all of the previous sales for each month, you will have to keep track of the total sales somehow.  The Aggregate function works okay for this because we can build a list and use its last element as the current total for calculating the next element.

```
var sales = Enumerable.Range(1,12).Select(x => x * 10).ToList();
var sums = sales.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (list, sale) => list.Concat(new List<int>{list.LastOrDefault() + sale});
```